# how to save mutiple values at application startup in sequqlize (Node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am in need of saving multiple values for on column at startup of application. My code of model is as below:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var speclization = sequelize.define("speclization",
        {
            speclizationname: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    ).create(
        {
            speclizationname: 'Computer Science'
        },
        {
            speclizationname: 'Information Technology'
        },
        {
            speclizationname: 'Electronics'
        },
        {
            speclizationname: 'Electrical'
        }
    );
    return speclization;
};
```

Above code only save only first value in database and i did not find any doc regarding to this. I am using MySql database here.

Comment: Why don't you use `model.bulkCreate`?

Comment: @Adam In this case no data is saving in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var speclization = sequelize.define("speclization",
        {
            speclizationname: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    ).bulkCreate([
        {
            speclizationname: 'Computer Science'
        },
        {
            speclizationname: 'Information Technology'
        },
        {
            speclizationname: 'Electronics'
        },
        {
            speclizationname: 'Electrical'
        }
    ]);
    return speclization;
};
```

Comment: I was not using it correctly. when i start my application and if table is not there then it give an error that table does not exist. Can you please tell me where should i put my code for inserting data in table at application creation.